# SharePoint Server Farm, what to do with an old server?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infrastructure, sharepoint

so we've procured a monster of a SQL Cluster and 4 screaming fast machines running the apps/WFE to start up our MOSS 2007 Enterprise Server farm, however I've got one server from the old server farm configuration that was just re-imaged and is still running decently, it's a 32 bit machine where the others are 64 bit machines so it really can't serve the same role as a 64 bit machine.  I'd like to see if there's a role for it somewhere in the farm, a few thoughts:

--Dedicated Search Query Server
--Dedicated Excel Services

Has anyone out there been in a similar situation? What did they do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not recommended to mix 32 bit and 64 bit inside of the same farm.  Upgrades (Service Packs, CU) can lead to issues.

Probably best to take that machine and repurpose for something outside of SharePoint.

Comment: Was afraid someone would say that...oh well thanks for the validation.